# Why does my data flow finishes before all async calls are fully processed from BufferBlock?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a data flow as follows.

**1.** A task that reads a text file in chunks and adds them to `BatchBlock<chunkSize>`

**2.** An `ActionBlock` that is linked to the above `BatchBlock` that partitions the data into batches and adds them to a `BufferBlock`

**3.** A `TransformationBlock` that is linked to `BufferBlock`, which spawns an `async` task for each batch

**4.** The process is finished when all the spanwed `async` calls are finished.

The below code isn't working as expected. It finishes before all batches are processed. What am I missing?

```
private static void DataFlow(string filePath, int chunkSize, int batchSize)
{
    int chunkCount = 0;
    int batchCount = 0;

    BatchBlock<string> chunkBlock = new BatchBlock<string>(chunkSize);
    BufferBlock<IEnumerable<string>> batchBlock = new BufferBlock<IEnumerable<string>>();

    Task produceTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
        {
            chunkBlock.Post(line);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished producing");
        chunkBlock.Complete();
    });

    var makeBatches = new ActionBlock<string[]>(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got a chunk  " + ++chunkCount);

        // Partition each chunk into smaller chunks grouped on column 1
        var partitions = t.GroupBy(c => c.Split(',')[0], (key, g) => g);

        // Further beakdown the chunks into batch size groups
        var groups = partitions.Select(x => x.Select((i, index) => new { i, index }).GroupBy(g => g.index / batchSize, e => e.i));

        // Get batches from groups
        var batches = groups.SelectMany(x => x).Select(y => y.Select(z => z));

        foreach (var batch in batches)
        {
            batchBlock.Post(batch);
        }

        batchBlock.Complete();

    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });

    chunkBlock.LinkTo(makeBatches, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    var executeBatches = new TransformBlock<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<string>>(async b =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got a batch  " + ++batchCount);
        await ExecuteBatch(b);
        return b;

    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded });

    batchBlock.LinkTo(executeBatches, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    var finishBatches = new ActionBlock<IEnumerable<string>>(b =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finised executing  batch" + batchCount);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded });

    executeBatches.LinkTo(finishBatches, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    Task.WaitAll(produceTask);
    Console.WriteLine("Production complete");

    makeBatches.Completion.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Making batches complete");

    executeBatches.Completion.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Executing batches complete");

    Task.WaitAll(finishBatches.Completion);

    Console.WriteLine("Process complete with total chunks " + chunkCount + " and total batches " + batchCount);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

// async task to simulate network I/O
private static async Task ExecuteBatch(IEnumerable<string> batch)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executing batch ");
    await Task.Run(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`chunkBlock` is calling `makeBatches` with each chunk, and you're calling `batchBlock.Complete()` within `makeBatches`, so after the first batch it quits accepting new posts.

Comment: Dax. Hummm makes sense. Where should I call batchBlock.Complete?

Comment: I don't know offhand, I don't know TPL-dataflow at all.  It *kind of* looks like `ActionBlock` is meant to be something of a terminal block; I'd investigate if there's something else like a `TransformBlock` or something that lets you do what you want but propogate completion as well.

Comment: @user330612 Looks like instead of an `ActionBlock` you could use a `TransformManyBlock` to do the transform, and then link that to the next step with a `PropogateCompletion=true` option.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing here completion propagation and direct flow. Your `makeBatches` and `executeBatches` aren't linked between each other, which is bad. But the real issue here is this lines:

```
foreach (var batch in batches)
{
    batchBlock.Post(batch);
}

// this line stops the batchBlock to accept any news messages    
batchBlock.Complete();
```

You do complete the `batchBlock` after the first batch, after this line it will not accept any other messages. As @DaxFohl said, you need to change your `makeBatches` from [`ActionBlock<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx) to [`TransformManyBlock<string, IEnumerable<string>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194784.aspx) (so you'll provide many chunks), and after that link it to the next block:

```
var makeBatches = new TransformManyBlock<string[], IEnumerable<string>>(t =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Got a chunk  " + ++chunkCount);

    // Partition each chunk into smaller chunks grouped on column 1
    var partitions = t.GroupBy(c => c.Split(',')[0], (key, g) => g);

    // Further beakdown the chunks into batch size groups
    var groups = partitions.Select(x => x.Select((i, index) => new { i, index }).GroupBy(g => g.index / batchSize, e => e.i));

    // Get batches from groups
    return groups.SelectMany(x => x).Select(y => y.Select(z => z));
});

makeBatches.LinkTo(executeBatches, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

Some other thoughts: You do not need to provide a [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx), as [this is default value for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228609.aspx), and, maybe, [you can use a `BatchBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228602.aspx) for chunking your strings. A little bit late, but still better than never :)